# Is there a way to re-assign cases to a particular location (organization) in CommCare HQ?

Tags: commcare

I'd like to reassign cases in bulk to a new location/organization in CommCare HQ, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Case Importer or with the "Reassign Cases" feature.

Case Importer: You need to set the owner_id of the case to the commcare_id of the location you want to assign them to.

Reassign Cases: Data -> Reassign Cases. You can use the standard report filters in the Reassign Cases screen to select the ones you want to reassign. This works well if your reassign rule is straightforward like "move all cases assigned to Location A to Location B".

But if your reassignment rule is more complex and based on case properties (i.e. only assign HIV Positive Females to location B) you should export the cases to Excel then use the case importer to do the reassignment.